# Eliminar de mi cuenta un servicio de TFS

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de querer obtener la lista de servidores TFS desde VS2017 RC. Cuando quiero obtener la lista de servicios me sale el error TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://.com.

¿Cómo puedo desconectar mi cuenta de ese servidor para que no me siga saliendo el servicio?

Cuando reviso mi perfil me sigue saliendo

[image: Visual Studio Team Services Accounts]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Esta fue la respuesta por parte de Microsoft:

> You need to contact someone that is a member of that site and have
>   them delete your account email from the Users Hub in
>   XXXXXXXXX.visualstudio.com and then XXXXXXXXX.visualstudio.com will be
>   removed from your profile.
>
> If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

Por si alguien pueda llegar a tener el mismo problema